# Color-box behind inline text / inline math without vertical space

Tags: color, boxes, line-spacing, height

I'd like to provide a ‘background-colour’ for spans of code or math inline with text, in the same way that CSS allows. I've tried to do this with `\colorbox`, but unfortunately, that seems to add vertical alignment issues:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.89}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
$\mathsf{A \rightarrow P(x)}$
\blindtext
\colorbox{light-gray}{$\mathsf{A \rightarrow P(x)}$}
This is a sentence, after-which another formula with colour will be on the next line.
\colorbox{light-gray}{$\mathsf{A \rightarrow P(x)}$}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Product:
[image]

I'd much prefer the colour to ‘bleed’ into the space dedicated to above/below lines, if that makes sense (i.e. still be ‘tall’, as it is by default, taller than the line-height; but for it to not affect the effective line-height of the lines it's in.)

Comment: if you know the content will fit in the line without the box then `\smash{\colorbox{...` will safely hide the height

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version without `\colorbox` (apart from the example), but using the very nice `\tcbhighmath` command from `tcolorbox` and the configurable settings of `highlight math style={....}`

The most important setting is `size=tight`, but there is `size=minimal` too!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.89}

\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced jigsaw,size=tight,colback=light-gray,boxrule=0pt,sharp corners}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
$\mathsf{A \rightarrow P(x)}$
\blindtext
\tcbhighmath{\mathsf{A \rightarrow P(x)}}
This is a sentence, after-which another formula with colour will be on the next line.
\colorbox{light-gray}{$\mathsf{A \rightarrow P(x)}$}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! Is there a way to render `\tcbhighmath` output using textstyle? In particular, have it use `\tfrac` instead of `\dfrac`?

Answer (score 3):

`\colorbox` adds padding on the four sides; you want to remove it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.89}

\newcommand{\graybg}[1]{%
  \begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% no padding
  \colorbox{light-gray}{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
$\mathsf{A \rightarrow P(x)}$
\blindtext
\graybg{$\mathsf{A \rightarrow P(x)}$}
This is a sentence, after-which another formula with colour will be on the next line.
\graybg{$\mathsf{A \rightarrow P(x)}$}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you instead want the padding, but that it doesn't interfere with the vertical spacing, smash the color box, but add a vertical phantom with the actual size.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.89}

\newcommand{\graybg}[1]{%
  \mbox{\vphantom{#1}\smash{\colorbox{light-gray}{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
$\mathsf{A \rightarrow P(x)}$
\blindtext
\graybg{$\mathsf{A \rightarrow P(x)}$}
This is a sentence, after-which another formula with colour will be on the next line.
\graybg{$\mathsf{A \rightarrow P(x)}$}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe you want a mix between the two methods. The default value of `\fboxsep` is 3pt.

Comment: Can I do this *without* reducing the effective size of the coloured region? Something like a margin with negative padding in CSS?

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE I just added it

Comment: One thing to note, is that this doesn't line wrap.